# Text overflows ListTile - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, overflow

I want the subtitle of my ListTile to be hidden when it reaches  the end of list tile.
What i Get:
[image]
What I want:
[image]
If i give `overflow:TextOverflow.ellipsis` to the Text Widget i get this:
[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 19,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 60,
            crossAxisSpacing: 60),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(
              " title ",
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              " this is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitle",
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
            tileColor: Colors.grey[200],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try maxline property in text

```
         Text(
            "example",
            maxLines: 3,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use "maxLines" to give the number of lines for text.

Like this :

```
     return ListTile(
        title: Text(
          " title ",
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
          " this is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitlethis is a very long subtitle",
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          maxLines: 3,
        ),
        tileColor: Colors.grey[200],
      );
```